# Prove that: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}=\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

Find the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}$$

My attempt, I can prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}$ is not uniformly convergent on $[a,\infty)$, hence I can't switch the limit and series. Then I choose to compute the series first,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+n^2}=\frac\pi{2x}\coth(\pi x)-\frac1{2x^2}$$

then compute the limit

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\pi\coth(\pi x)-\frac1{x}\right)=\pi$$

My question is, how to compute this limit without computing the closed form for the series? It seems also difficult to prove the limit is convergent before getting a closed form for the series.

Comment: My guess: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2x}{x^2+n^2} = \frac 1x \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{1+(n/x)^2}$ approximates $\int_0^\infty \frac{2}{1+t^2} dt$.

Comment: Wolframalpha confirms that   
 Limit[Sum[2 (x/(x^2 + n^2)), {n, 1, Infinity}], x -> Infinity] = Pi

Answer (score 3):

Fix $q>1$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{q\lfloor x\rfloor} \frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}+\sum_{n=q\lfloor x\rfloor+1}^\infty \frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}$$

where

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{q\lfloor x\rfloor} \frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{q\lfloor x\rfloor} \frac{2}{1+\left(\frac nx\right)^2}\cdot \frac1x=\int_0^q\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt=2\arctan q\tag{1}$$
For tail part, let $k=n-q\lfloor x\rfloor$

$$\sum_{n=q\lfloor x\rfloor+1}^\infty \frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2x}{x^2+(qx+k)^2}\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2x}{(qx)^2+k^2}=\frac1q \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2qx}{(qx)^2+k^2}$$

Let $p=qx$

$$\frac1q\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2p}{p^2+k^2}\approx \frac1q\int_0^\infty \frac{2p}{p^2+k^2}dk=\frac{2\arctan p}q\le \frac\pi q$$

since $q$ is arbitrary, let $q\to\infty$, then the tail part

$$\sum_{n=q\lfloor x\rfloor+1}^\infty \frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}\le\frac\pi q\to 0$$

and (1) goes to $2\arctan q\to \pi$, hence

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}=\pi$$